# cannot make a div appear beneath the others

Tags: html, css, input, upload

I'm trying to build a picture upload element, with a progressbar underneath;

here is my html

```
<div id="profile_pic_box">
     <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="avatar" data-url="/php_parsers/photo_system.php" multiple>
    <img src="/myDir/user/'.$profile_id.'/'.$avatar.'" id="avatar_pic" alt="Tutor'.$id.' Profile Picture">
<div id="progress">
<div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
<div id='avatar_status'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
div#profile_pic_box{ width:200px; height:200px; margin:20px auto 0px auto; overflow-y:hidden;}
div#profile_pic_box > img{z-index:2000; width:200px;}
div#profile_pic_box > a {
    width:200px;
    height:3%;
    display: none;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom: 72%;
    left: 11%;
    z-index:4000;
    background:#F1F3F4; 
    color:6F6F78;
    border:#F1F3F4 1px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
}

div#profile_pic_box > input{
    display:none;
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:3000;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:.8;
    width:inherit;
    background:#F1F3F4; 
    height:inherit;

}

div#profile_pic_box:hover a {
    display: block;
}

div#profile_pic_box:hover input {
    display: block;
}

div#profile_pic_box >div{
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

#avatar_pic{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

The problem is that the #progress and the .bar are underneath the  tag and so cannot be seen. How can i get them to drop and show below the image? How can I make them 'stack' on top of one another?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I just adjusted your html.

```
<div id="profile_pic_box">
     <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="avatar" data-url="/php_parsers/photo_system.php" multiple>
    <img src="/myDir/user/'.$profile_id.'/'.$avatar.'" id="avatar_pic" alt="Tutor'.$id.' Profile Picture">
</div>

<div id="progress">
<div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
<div id='avatar_status'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just got this actually! it's useful writing out the problem - I will accept this shortly - Thanks